# I can't use the module I created in my main python file

Tags: module

I created a module named module_1:

```
def learn(programming_lang):
  print("I am learning " + programming_lang)
```

and I want to use it in my main Python file.

```
module_1.learn("Python")
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

in main Python file add this line

```
import module_1
```

Comment: I've already done that and mentioned it above https://stackoverflow.com/a/73535838/15296744 Thanks :)